# If I find a meteorite do I get to keep it?

Tags: civil-law

If I find a meteorite do I get to keep it? Does it make a difference if I find it in my own lawn or on public land? I am especially interested how law is in European countries.

Comment: This really depends on which European country you are talking about... In France, you may be able to keep it even if you are not the landowner. In Switzerland, the State owns it but must pay you. In the UK it's not expressly decided, but it is generally accepted that it would be owned by the land owner. There isn't any universal law.

Comment: "keep" requires further definition.  In Canada a meteorite  can be the property of the finder, but cannot be removed from Canada..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

In most countries, meteorites belong to the state no matter where they are found or how long they have been there. If you found one on the high seas, it would belong to the nation of the vessel’s registration.

Comment: It's not that way in the US, but yes, it may be in other countries. Also some states (like Switzerland) will pay the finder "no more than the value" of the find.